# How can i make iframe output that html page is loaded by mobile version. that html page is Reactive web

Tags: html, iframe, web, ionic-framework

this code show pc version web page 
so i want to load mobile version page 
that page don't have additional mobile web page
it is Reactive web
please give me a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you detect mobile device by user-agent, you have to pass to iframe some parameter `<iframe src='site.com?loadMobile=true'>` and check it on server side.

If you have responsive web, then you have to fix your css code.

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
  /* your css code for this devide width */
}
```